# SQL query with AND OR operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query

```
SELECT entries.*, categories.name as name_cat, areas.name as name_area, sub_categories.name as name_sub
FROM entries, areas, sub_categories, categories
WHERE sub_categories.id= entries.id_sub
  AND **areas.id = entries.area**
  AND categories.id = entries.id_cat
ORDER BY entries.id DESC
```

It works good but i do have some BLANK fields in **entries.area** .. which is not coming in result..

I try few changes in query but some give me result while some give less nothing gives me proper Answer

Comment: Store NULL instead of blanks, then do LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh : Hi, Alright can you write a LEFT join query for me?

Comment: See Spencer's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 2015 already. It's past time to ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operator, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead. With the `JOIN` keyword, we can move the predicates (conditions) from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause.

Using the `JOIN` keyword, we can specify an "outer join" by including additional keyword(s).

For example, including the keyword `LEFT` (before `JOIN`) specifies that the query should return rows from the table on the "left" side even when no matching row exists in the table on the right side.

```
 SELECT entries.*
      , categories.name      AS name_cat
      , areas.name           AS name_area
      , sub_categories.name  AS name_sub
   FROM entries
   LEFT
   JOIN areas
     ON areas.id = entries.area
   LEFT
   JOIN sub_categories
     ON sub_categories.id= entries.id_sub
   LEFT
   JOIN categories
     ON categories.id = entries.id_cat
  WHERE 1=1
  ORDER BY entries.id DESC
```

The line `WHERE 1=1` can be omitted... I included it just to show where a `WHERE` clause would go, if we needed one.

Comment: @spencer7593  . . . Along with ditching commas in the `FROM` clause, I would suggest that you also use table aliases so queries are easier to write and to read.